# XCode simulator runtime is not supported on macOS 11.1

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

The app I am working on support iOS 9 so I need to test it on simulator, but as I updated mac os and installed new xCode it  looks like its impossible.

[image]

Maybe some one can give an advice how to enable these old iOS simulators in XCode.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: which version of Xcode ?

Comment: @zeytin Version 12.3 (12C33)